# Does SHAP in Python support Keras or TensorFlow models while using DeepExplainer?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, shap

I am currently using SHAP Package to determine the feature contributions. I have used the approach for XGBoost and RandomForest and it worked really well. Since the data I am working on is a sequential data I tried using LSTM and CNN to train the model and then get the feature importance using the SHAP's `DeepExplainer`; but it is continuously throwing error. The error I am getting is:

```
AssertionError: <class 'keras.callbacks.History'> is not currently a supported model type!.
```

I am attaching the sample code as well (LSTM). It would be helpful if someone could help me with it.

```
shap.initjs()
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, input_shape=(X.shape[1],X.shape[2]), return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(n_neurons, return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
h=model.fit(X, y, epochs=nb_epochs, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=1, shuffle=True)
background = X[np.random.choice(X.shape[0],100, replace=False)]
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(h,background)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The returned value of `model.fit` is not the model instance; rather, it's the history of training (i.e. stats like loss and metric values) as an instance of `keras.callbacks.History` class. That's why you get the mentioned error when you pass the returned `History` object to `shap.DeepExplainer`. Instead, you should pass the model instance itself:

```
explainer = shap.DeepExplainer(model, background)
```

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the help it does work, and also for making me understand the base problem as well.

Comment: Does it work whatever the way the Keras model is created? I am experiencing issues when I create the neural network with model subclassing.